# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (from WCF to ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have WCF service to store and retrieve messages (in/from a database). I'm calling it from ASP.NET.

When I run my app I face with following problem:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I don't actually understand how to cope with it.
Here's the class that throws the exception:

```
public class SendMessageClient
{
    private string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:49350/Service1.svc/";
    public bool sendMessage(Message message)
    {
        try
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Message));

            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(mem, message);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            webClient.UploadString(BASE_URL + "sendmessage", "POST", data);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

PS reference to wcf exists

Comment: Are you trying to use WebClient to call a WCF service?

Comment: it executes POST request, so I can't see it in browser, or what do you mean?

Comment: I've test service and it has problem with some syntax. Thank that you make me notice it!

Comment: If there is a 400 error, the format of the request is wrong. You need to check whether the WCF service supports your http request. In other words, some parameters of your http request are wrong. You can refer to this link, which contains how to enable the help document:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066716/wcf-service-works-locally-but-gives-404-on-server/62078779#62078779.   The help document will tell you how to send the correct request to the WCF service.

Comment: Yes, actually I had to check whether my WCF is working in the right way, because it's an error occured by wrong procedure in web service. Test your service first. Hope this will help you to solve your problem!